# Using Gerrit for Code Reviews

Tags: git, github, gerrit

My team uses GIT and wants to use a code review tool where we can do the following :

- Record comments and mark them as tags/labels and have a way to pull them up and examine the results of the code reviews later. For e.g. 'X' number of code reviews happened last month and we added comments with various tags/labels. I would want to create a report based on how many code reviews were conducted and the tags/labels count.

Is Gerrit a code option for this ? How difficult/easy is it to setup ? Can I do this with the GitHub PR (Pull Request) ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a reviewnotes plugin for Gerrit. Checkout this blog for more details what you can do with it: http://blog.adamspiers.org/2013/10/02/more-uses-for-git-notes/